# Does CCG Know that Haise Sasaki is Actually Ken Kaneki?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I just started the 3rd season, but I read the wiki, and I was curious.... Didn't CCG capture Kaneki and got the idea for the Quinx because of him? Then why did they let "Eyepatch" join the CCG as an investor (and gave him such a high status, too)? I know for a fact that CCG knows that he is a ghoul, so doesn't that mean they know that he's Kaneki?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the Manga:

Haise Sasaki is an Alter Ego of Ken Kaneki. Ken Kaneki was completely broken down and brainwashed. The knowledge that Ken Kaneki, the person, is a ghoul, is not common knowledge in the CCG, only a selected few know about this. They also don't know that Sasaki is Kaneki, and he doesn't know himself. For all that matters for most of the investigators of the GCC, the Eyepatch/Centerpede ghoul has been disposed of by Kisho Arima, if they know at all. Except for a selected few, the CCG thinks of Sasaki as a Quinx user (if even, I'm actually not sure if he ever used his Kakuhou while in the CCG), although he is none.

And the idea of the Quinx didn't come from Kaneki, it came from [Ryoujirou Shiba](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Shiba). He actually did this better than the guy who did this to Kaneki, Akihiro Kano, the latter coming to admire the work of Shiba later on.